# How to Remove Square bracket from JSON

Tags: javascript, json, arrays

I have one json string like below

```
[

    {
        "Name": "TEST",
        "deviceId": "",
        "CartId": "",
        "timestamp": 1383197265540,
        "FOOD": [],
        "City": "LONDON CA"
     }

]
```

I want to delete/remove the first and last square brackets from string..So how would I remove the first and last square brackets from the above string using javascript.

Please help me

Comment: var newString = jsonString.substring(1, jsonString.length-1);

Comment: Parse it, get the 1st element, and stringify that.

Comment: @SohilDesai thanks for your help..its working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
var tmpStr = '[    
    {
        "Name": "TEST",
        "deviceId": "",
        "CartId": "",
        "timestamp": 1383197265540,
        "FOOD": [],
        "City": "LONDON CA"
     }

]';

var newStr = tmpStr.substring(1, tmpStr.length-1);
```

See [this codepen example](https://codepen.io/jaq316/pen/oNXaZWJ)

Comment: I prefer the answer of 'properties[0]' because that actually works with the json object rather than hacking it by manipulating a string.

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat... Can you be more specific?

Comment: @HimmatSinghDulawat. I beg to differ. See the codepen example (https://codepen.io/jaq316/pen/oNXaZWJ)

Answer (score 21):

Use this when you return:

```
return properties[0];
```

Or

```
var data = [

{
    "Name": "TEST",
    "deviceId": "",
    "CartId": "",
    "timestamp": 1383197265540,
    "FOOD": [],
    "City": "LONDON CA"
 }

]; // Or whatever the Json is
data = data[0];
```

Or if you're accessing the json via another object

```
var data = jsonObj[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
var A = [{}]; var B = {}; A = [

    {
        "Name": "TEST",
        "deviceId": "",
        "CartId": "",
        "timestamp": 1383197265540,
        "FOOD": [],
        "City": "LONDON CA"
     }

]

B = A[0]; console.log(B); //required output
```

Comment: What is A has multiple JSON object then A[0] will fail for second and subsequent objects.

Comment: If "A" has multiple JSON object, you can probably loop the array and store individual items into a new object. But the question has a specific condition, for which A[0] should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
.replace(/[[\]]/g, '')
```