# Neo4j JSON Objects to Elements

Tags: ruby, json, neo4j, sinatra, neography

I'm not sure that I'm using the correct terminology, so feel free to correct it when necessary. I (think) I have JSON objects that I'm attempting to convert into an array of elements.

I'm using Neography in Ruby to query a Neo4j database, and when I receive the results back, I need them to look like this:

```
["apple","orange","pear"]
```

However, they look like this:

```
[["apple"],["orange"],["pear"]]
```

The Ruby I'm using to create this is:

```
cypher = "MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*#{term}.*' RETURN n.name"
results = neo.execute_query(cypher)["data"].to_json
puts results
results
```

I'd read here ([How to Remove Square bracket from JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19699452/how-to-remove-square-bracket-from-json)) to try parsing the JSON, and getting the first element.

```
cypher = "MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*#{term}.*' RETURN n.name"
results = neo.execute_query(cypher)["data"].to_json  
results = JSON.parse(results)
puts results
results.to_s # deals with Sinatra not being able to display a hash?
```

But gotten the same double-bracket results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest looking into the Neo4j.rb project (the `neo4j-core` and `neo4j` gems).  Full disclosure: I'm one of the maintainers ;).  With `neo4j-core` you might do:

```
neo4j_session = Neo4j::Session.open(:server_db, 'http://neo4j:password@localhost:7474')
cypher = "MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*#{term}.*' RETURN n.name AS name"
results = neo4j_session.query(cypher).map(&:name)
```

You should be using parameters in general, though, to prevent injection attacks:

```
cypher = "MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ {regex} RETURN n.name AS name"
results = neo4j_session.query(cypher, regex: "(?i).*#{term}.*").map(&:name)
```

You can also use the `Query` API which will make params for you and also convert Ruby regular expressions to Cypher syntax:

```
results = neo4j_session.query.match(n: :Person).where(n: {name: /#{term}/i}).pluck('n.name')
```

If you use `ActiveNode` from the `neo4j` gem it's even simpler:

```
class Person
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name, type: String
end

Person.where(name: /#{term}/i).pluck(:name)
```

You could even make a search method on the `Person` model to do that for you:

```
class Person
  include Neo4j::ActiveNode

  property :name, type: String

  def search(term)
    all.where(name: /#{term}/i)
  end
end

Person.search(term).pluck(:name)
```

Comment: I think is getting me a lot closer. If I use the first example, I still end up with AppleOrangePear, but I can finally push each 'result' into an array, and the rest of the script works as expected on the front end. The second example--parameters to avoid injection attacks--I keep getting "Neo4j::Server::CypherResponse::ResponseError - Expected a parameter named term:" -- I see you and Chris discussing this on your GitHub, but I can't find parallels. Ex. 3 isn't doing the regex from above. Quickly this all gets out of my understanding. Should I be using SearchKick as you suggest elsewhere?

Comment: Sorry, that was my bad!  I should have named the parameter in the query string `{regex}` because that was the key of the hash I was passing in as the second argument to the `query` method.  I've edited the answer to fix it

Comment: The later examples pass in a Ruby regular expression which is converted into the Cypher regular expression syntax.  i.e. when you end the Ruby regex with `i` it specifies a case-insensitive match and thus that is translated to the `(?i)` prefix in Cypher

Comment: `searchkick` is definitely nice, but it has it's limitations.  Namely if you have a lot of records (like, millions) then when you do `Model.reindex` it's going to try to paginate them which can be slow in Neo4j.  Also only the changes made through your Ruby app get recorded in elasticsearch.  I would check out this plugin for Neo4j: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-elasticsearch

Comment: Lastly ;)  If you have other questions we (the Neo4j.rb team) hang out on https://gitter.im/neo4jrb/neo4j or you can chat with the larger Neo4j community on their public Slack group: http://neo4j.com/blog/public-neo4j-users-slack-group/

Answer (score 0):

This

```
cypher = "MATCH (n:Person) WHERE n.name =~ '(?i).*#{term}.*' RETURN n.name"
results = neo.execute_query(cypher)["data"].flatten
```

should work

Comment: For me, this is resulting in: AppleOrangePear

Comment: Edited my solution based on your comment. Results should already be an array - no need parsing the response from neography. You can verify that by running `puts results.kind_of?(Array)` at the end.

Comment: Same problem. It verified as an array. But, to be clear--when I do puts results, I'm getting each puts individually (like Apple\nOrange\nPear), but when what's returned (to the browser) is AppleOrangePear